# prove there cannot exist distinct reals $x$, $y$, $u$, $v$

Tags: inequality

prove there cannot exist distinct reals $x$, $y$, $u$, $v$ such that $x^2+y^2=u^2+v^2$
and $x^3+y^3=u^3+v^3$ hold simultaneously.

Can it be solved by considering

1. $x>y>u>v$
2. $x=y>u>v$
3. $x=u>y>v$

and other similar cases?

Comment: and $$u=x,v=y$$? should are all variables distinct?

Comment: didnt't get you

Comment: Don't downvote it, this question came in Madhava Math Competition. Apparently it is wrong that's why I found so long to find its solution so please don't downvote it as it makes it harder for people to find it

Answer (score 2):

The claim is simply false. If we consider $(a,b)=(3,4)$ or $(a,b)=(4.61313\ldots, -1.92847\ldots)$ we have $a^2+b^2=25$ and $a^3+b^3=91$. In other terms, the sum of squares and the sum of cubes do not fix a unique couple of real numbers, in the general case.

Comment: Explicitly, the other real pair is $(a,b)$, where
$$
a =
\frac
{-7+3\sqrt{17}+\sqrt{-2+42\sqrt{17}}}
{4}
$$
$$
b =
\frac
{-7+3\sqrt{17}-\sqrt{-2+42\sqrt{17}}}
{4}
$$

Comment: @quasi Could you tell how to calculate those numbers

Comment: @Anshuman Agrawal: Letting $s=a+b$ and $p=ab$, the equations
$$
a^2+b^2=3^2+4^2\\
a^3+b^3=3^3+4^3
$$
can be rewritten as
$$
s^2-2p=25\\
s(s^2-3p)=91
$$
Eliminating $p$, we get
$$
(s-7)(s^2+7s-26)=0
$$
Of the three solutions for $s$, the solution $s=7$ yields $(a,b)=(3,4)$ or $(a,b)=(4,3)$, and of the other two solutions for $s$, one yields non-real values of $a,b$, and the other yields the values of $a,b$ shown in my previous comment.